# Configuring log rotate in Lumen 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2

I tried to configure log rotation on Lumen but I'm stuck. I know how to do this with Laravel, but (one more time) I'm lost with Lumen.

I tried to add this in `app/bootstrap.php`, because I read it somewhere:

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function(Monolog\Logger $monolog) use ($app) {
    $monolog->pushHandler(
        new \Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler($app->storagePath().'/logs/lumen.log', 5)
    );
});
```

And I can view this error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function error() on null in /x/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Exceptions/Handler.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 /x/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(36): Laravel\Lumen\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#1 /x/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RegistersExceptionHandlers.php(123): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#2 /x/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RegistersExceptionHandlers.php(51): Laravel\Lumen\Application->handleUncaughtException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#3 [internal function]: Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(Object(Error))
#4 {main}
  thrown in /x/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 36
```

I don't understand what does it mean, and what I should do.

**Does someone has succeeded in rotating log in lumen 5.2?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **forget returning** the object, it should be:

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function(Monolog\Logger $monolog) use ($app) {
    return $monolog->pushHandler(
        new \Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler($app->storagePath().'/logs/lumen.log', 5)
    );
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Another idea:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler;

class LogServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Configure logging on boot.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $maxFiles = 7;

        $handlers[] = (new RotatingFileHandler(storage_path('logs/lumen.log'), $maxFiles))
            ->setFormatter(new LineFormatter(null, null, true, true));

        $this->app['log']->setHandlers($handlers);
    }

    /**
     * Register the log service.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // Log binding already registered in vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php.
    }
}
```

Then don't forget to add the service provider to your Lumen bootstrap/app.php:

```
$app->register(\App\Providers\LogServiceProvider::class);
```